# General equation for solution series to two sine curves with different amplitudes, periods and phases

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Consider we have two sine curves of different periods ($P_{1,2}$), amplitudes ($A_{1,2}$) and starting phases ($\theta_{1,2}$), e.g.

$$x=A_{1} \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{P_{1}}-\theta_{1} \right)$$

and

$$y=A_{2} \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{P_{2}}-\theta_{2} \right)$$

Is it possible to calculate a series of solutions for $t$ such that $x=y$? I know that if $A_{1}=A_{2}$ then it is simple as you just solve for inside the sine parenthesises, but since the two sine curves have different amplitudes I am not quite sure.

Perhaps it's not possible to do this analytically, but if this is the case perhaps someone could suggest some numerical or approximate solutions?

Comment: If a solution exists at $x=x_1$, then another solution will also exist at $x=x_1+k\cdot\text{LCM}(P_1, P_2)$, where $k\in \text{Z}$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you sure this is correct? Consider P2 > P1 and A2 > A1. From that we know that there will be a zero point as y crosses x at least twice on every period P2, but you won't necessarily get this with your equation.

Comment: oh I am sorry I didn't notice that first was equation in $x$ and second in $y$. The solution is wrong. I think it'll be hard to find general solution to such a problem!